# jMeter - XPath Extractor does not let BSF Post Processor (with javascript code) to access multiple extracted matches

Tags: javascript, variables, xpath, jmeter

I have an XML response from server (SOAP) and I'm getting multiple values in it. XPath extracts all the values and stores them internally like Match_1, Match_2, Match_3, etc.
But I can't access them neither via BSF Post Processor nor via JavaScript code pasted in XML. It just refuses to return values then I address to them like this: `${Match_1}`.

Example:

Response returns multiple `contentGroupID` values.
Debug Sampler reveals them:

- contentGroupID=67
- contentGroupID_1=67
- contentGroupID_2=50
- contentGroupID_3=38
- contentGroupID_4=54
- contentGroupID_5=46

We need to use each of these values in the next single request, so we add a code inside XML in place where we need those values to sit:

```
${__javaScript
(myOutput =''; var names = {};
for (var i = 1; i <= ${contentGroupID_matchNr}; i++) 
{names[i] = "${contentGroupID_" + i + "}";}
for (var j = 1; j <= ${contentGroupID_matchNr}; j++) 
{myOutput = 
myOutput + '<ns8:forContentGroupId><ns2:id>' + names[j] + '</ns2:id></ns8:forContentGroupId>';},
myOutput)
}
```

Here we place the part of XML with values `<ns8:forContentGroupId><ns2:id>' + ids + '</ns2:id></ns8:forContentGroupId>` as many times as matches were found by XPath.

But the magic does **not** happen. The request is sent as follows:

```
<ns8:forContentGroupId><ns2:id>${contentGroupID_1}</ns2:id></ns8:forContentGroupId>
<ns8:forContentGroupId><ns2:id>${contentGroupID_2}</ns2:id></ns8:forContentGroupId>
<ns8:forContentGroupId><ns2:id>${contentGroupID_3}</ns2:id></ns8:forContentGroupId>
<ns8:forContentGroupId><ns2:id>${contentGroupID_4}</ns2:id></ns8:forContentGroupId>
<ns8:forContentGroupId><ns2:id>${contentGroupID_5}</ns2:id></ns8:forContentGroupId>
```

The same happens in case I set BSF Post Processor with JavaScript code and add a variable in XML.

The question is: **how the hell can one access those magical values?**

P.S. Everything works great then I use ForEach Controller. But the trick is I need to make single request with all the values, not multiple requests one after another.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution here:

BSF Post Processor witch JavaScript code:

```
var myOutput = '';
var names = {};
var str;
var value = 0;
var match = vars.get("contentGroupID_matchNr");
for (var i = 1; i <= match; i++) 
{
var n = i.toString();
str = 'contentGroupID_' + n;
value = vars.get(str);
names[i] = value;
}

for (var j = 1; j <= match; j++) {
myOutput = myOutput +  '<ns8:forContentGroupId><ns2:id>' + names[j] + '</ns2:id></ns8:forContentGroupId>';
}
vars.put("array", myOutput);
```

Plus ${array} variable inside XML.

End of story! =)